# How do I put the Admin,User,Seller into the same table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

[image: This the image of the three tables]       <---The image

**So as i said  i want to put these three tables togather and be able to use each freely.**

Admin table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Admin] (
    [ID]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Admin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is unclear what you mean by *put these three tables together*.

Comment: *"`[Password] NVARCHAR (50) NULL`"*? That smells like a huge security problem. Passwords should ***never*** be stored as plain text, and should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Maybe a View: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/creating-views/create-view-with-join.php

Comment: If you are looking to create a releationship between the tables, look up `foreign key`

Comment: @GMB  i meant that making all the three tables in one table,  I don't know how but i think it has a "TYPE" or "ROLE" command .

Comment: @Larnu ,you are right but that is a diffrent problem that i can fix inside a textbox in ASP.NET                                                                                                                                           and this is just a project not a real thing like amazon

Comment: Amazon was once "just a project", @cheesecake .